# how can I get hazelcast to connect to zookeeper with nuix-rest API server?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, hazelcast

I have a nuix-rest API application where we have hazelcast embedded which basically is used for forming the cluster using tcp/ip default discovery mechanism.
Now we want to have a dynamic discovery mechanism using zookeeper for which we have created a JAR file from the hazelcast-zookeeper.
We are placed the JAR file in the lib folder but when we start the service we are getting this error: "there is no discovery strategy to create..."

How can I confirm if the JAR file is under the CLASS_PATH?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to include the hazelcast-zookeeper dependency to your project.
It seems that it can not find the class. Include the dependencies mentioned here

https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-zookeeper?tab=readme-ov-file#configuration-via-maven

Comment: The dependency that is mentioned, we have already created a JAR file out of it and we have also put this JAR file under the /lib folder of our nuix-rest application and then we try to restart the service but we are still seen the same issue: "there is no discovery strategy to create"
How can I confirm if the JAR file is under the CLASS_PATH?